# Haskell - how to pattern match on backslash character?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I want to replace \n with a space in a String with a recursive function using pattern matching, but I can't figure out how to match the \ char.

This is my function:

```
replace :: String -> String
replace ('\\':'n':xs) = ' ' : replace xs
replace (x:xs) = x : replace xs
replace "" = ""
```

In `('\':'n':xs)` the backslash would escape the single quote and mess up the code, so I wrote `('\\':'n':xs)` expecting that the first \ would escape the escape of the second \ and would match a backslash in a String. However, it doesn't.

This is what happens when I try the function in GHCi:

```
*Example> replace "m\nop"
"m\nop"
*Example> replace "m\\nop"
"m op"
```

How can I match a single backslash?

Comment: Are you aware that `"m\nop"` is `['m', '\n', 'o', 'p']`? `\n` is a single character, not two.

Comment: No, I was not. And that is the actual answer to my question :) I changed the pattern to ('\n':xs) and this does behave as I expected the above to behave. Thank you!

Comment: Also consider `replace = unwords . lines`, though that has different behavior when there are multiple newlines in a row.

Comment: Now, for the questions sake, suppose there was no newline involved (or any other \x style special character), but I was trying to replace \ with /. For instance to convert a windows path to a *nix path. I am still not sure how to go about this.

Comment: @Willemijn: Keep in mind that `"\\"` is the escape sequence for a single `\ ` and you can probably use `map (\x -> if x == '\\'  then '/' else x)`. However, in practice you wouldn't bother with raw file paths but instead use a package like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/filepath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\n` is a single character. If we use `\n` in a string like `"Hello\nWorld!"`, then the resulting list looks like this: `['H','e','l','l','o','\n','W','o','r','l','d','!']`. `\n` denotes a newline character, a [single ASCII byte `10`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). However, since a newline isn't really easy to type in many programming languages, the escape sequence `\n` is used instead in string literals.

If you want to pattern match on a newline, you must use the whole escape sequence:

```
replace :: String -> String
replace ('\n':xs) = ' ' : replace xs
replace (x:xs)    = x   : replace xs
replace ""        = ""
```

Otherwise, you will only match the literal `\`.

**Exercise:** Now that `replace` works, try to use `map` instead of explicit recursion.